# Rails ajax first request not showing up unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a view that has a form to create a new post using Ajax, and it also renders all the posts and adds the newly added post to them. The problem is when I post the very first post, the page does not show it unless I refresh, then if I refresh it shows up and when I add more posts Ajax works fine.

Here is the view `index.html.erb` :

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
<%= link_to 'Edit my account', edit_user_registration_path %>
<%= form_tag search_posts_path, method: :get do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<b> Study requests </b>

<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>

        <%=f.label :Course_name %>
        <%=f.select :course_name, options_for_select(course_names) %><br/>

        <%=f.label :Course_number %>
        <%=f.select :course_number, options_for_select(course_numbers) %> <br/>

        <%=f.submit %>
<% end %>
<%= render @posts %>
```

The partial is `_post.html.erb` :

```
div id="post">
    <%= post.user_name%>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('id DESC')
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

        @post.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: "Study request successfully added" }
            format.js {}
            format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
        end
    end
```

And finally my `create.js.erb` :

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>").prependTo("#post");
```

Comment: Have you looked at request/response you send by ajax? What does the response look like?

Comment: Alex, I have not, where can I find these?

Comment: oh I see what you mean, I will take a look.

Comment: Depends on which browser you use. Usually you have to open developer tools (F12 button in Chrome and Firefox). Then choose Network and then filter requests by XHR and find you request.

Comment: My request is right, its only posting one post. Also the status of the response is 200 ok.

Comment: Try to debug you js which should add post to you page. I mean you can listen to success, error events on submit your form. Try to put some code in there to realize whether it's being executed or not. Try to emulate form submit manually to ensure submitting works fine. And finally try to execute code from your create.js.erb file to be sure it works.

Comment: you are using id post for a a lot of div in your post partial.and create.js.erb code was prepending it was before last post of your page instead of first page.Now you wrapped your partial call inside the div with id post so it picking the upper div and prepending post before it.But it will cause issue when you again post a new one it will append it between the last one you have posted and outer div with id post.

Comment: Ashutosh, I changed the div in create.js to container and it works now, read my answer below please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I only needed to add a new div around my partial rendering like this :

```
<ul id="container">
<%= render @posts %>
</ul>
```

And change the create.js to append to this div